# How do you link to an html file from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am working with a quiz programmed in JSON. After the quiz is finished, I would like to link to an html file. When I add the code (typical anchor tags), however, it breaks the code and doesn't display a link.

[image: link html from JSON]

I imagine that there is some kind of handler that I have to pass to the JSON file to let it know that I would like it to link to an external file.

Does anyone know how to do this is?

Comment: json doesn't know **ANYTHING** about html, not should it ever. If you're inserting a link and the link breaks the json, then you're doing something wrong - e.g. building the json by hand. Probably you tried to insert `<a href="...">...</a>` and the `"` quotes caused json syntax errors. e.g. you introduced a javascript syntax error.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.

Comment: Then you'd have to insert the link as `<a href=\"...\">`. note the backslash escapes on the `"`-quotes. Remember that JSON is essentially javascript. You have to follow basic javascript syntax rules, which means the `var foo = "foo "bar" baz";` is an outright syntax error.

Comment: That worked! I'm new to this stuff, so I figured the solution would be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the link in a JSON key: value pair. Then when you are parsing your .json file search for the "click here" text in the results key and apply the link from your link key:value.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8dj7h/2/

JS

```
var quizJSON = {
    results: "To review this topic click here",
    resultsLink: "http://google.com"
}

$('.json').append(quizJSON.results);
$(".json").html(function () {
    return $(".json").html().replace('click here', '<a href="' + quizJSON.resultsLink + '">click here</a>'); 
});;
```